# How to get file names via REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

So, fun fact: Most of the "title" attributes for the documents on my Sharepoint site are not only wrong, but also all the same. Consequently, I can't tell which file is which when I "getbytitle()" because apparently the true filename isn't delivered in the output for that.

I haven't found a lot of information on what's available in the API. Is there another call I can make to get actual file names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which API? From the "getbytitle()" I'm guessing the REST API.

"Title" is an optional property in SharePoint libraries. It is often populated by default from the metadata in the document, but can be set by the user.

To get a document by filename use the FileLeafRef property:

```
/sites/yourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/Items?$filter=FileLeafRef eq 'AdventureWorksBikes.xlsx'
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what I'm doing, then. I'm making a call to: `https://(my_sharepoint_site)/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=1&$top=1000000` and the XML response does not contain "FileLeafReq" at all. I should see many "xlsx" files, but that string doesn't appear in the XML response either. To be clear, I'm making a somewhat unorthodox call from Python using the "requests" library.

Comment: Specify your fields using $select.  For example: $select=FileLeafRef,Title,Created

Comment: Hot dog! That did the trick! I had no idea you could do that, thanks!

Comment: Matt, the REST API is very rich! If you want to browse a few examples, I have a GitHub project with around 70 REST examples and an editor to test your own. http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2017/04/a-sharepoint-rest-api-tester-with-ajax.html  and  https://github.com/microsmith/SharePointRESTtester

Comment: Many of the internal column names are listed here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_yeager/2008/11/03/reference-list-for-sharepoint-internal-field-names/  and you can discover your column names by going to List/Library Settings and clicking on the column name. The internal name will be in the URL.

Comment: Awesome! I've just begun exercising the opportunities available in the REST API, and it's exciting. Thanks!